# How to call a C++ constructor from a C-File

Tags: c++, c, oop, import, constructor

I've imported this program, which is parsing a lot of complex text and it's written in C. My own project is written in C++.

I actually intended, that whenever the parser-algorithm has found one of the key-tags then a one  (of many) constructor of my class should be called, so that I'll have a nice structure in the end of the txt, as a result of the parsing process.

**Here's the problem**: I learned OOP with Java and started C++ with this project, so I need a little help: how can I call a C++ constructor out of my C based parser file ? I already checked the internet, but either this question is too trivial or my intended solution is not working ;)

Thanks for any advises.

Comment: I think that if you compile with a c++ compilator and that you include your class definition in your c file it will work? Did you tried? It will just be like if everything was C++ but that you were using C inside it, who is something working.

Comment: @user3085931: Maybe your C program is a valid C++ program too, or you can change it that way with relatively little effort. (to a "valid" C++ program, not a beautiful one). A soon as you have a c++ program...treat it as C++ and everything is fine

Comment: @Mayerz: Not "every" C program is valid C++, and sometimes it´s valid but different behaviour

Comment: I liked that suggestion of Mayerz, would be the easiest way. But that C program is structured into different .c and .h files too. Would this still work in the end ?

Comment: @deviantfan Yep, I must admit that I was confused while writting my comment, I always thought integrating c inside c++ was trivial. the way I learnt to use C works in C++, I dont remember any big trouble.

Comment: @deviantfan the parser is rather complex and undocumented, I really don't want to touch a thing, if I don't have any other chance

Comment: @user3085931: Then go for a wrapper like in the answer of Michael Aaron Safyan below.

Comment: Ok, looking at Michael answer I must be wrong withiyt knowing it :)

Comment: The key problem is that C++ 'mangles' function names.  So all that is really necessary is to include the class header file, assure 'cplusplus' is defined, compile/link with a C++ compiler.  Note: for those functions that you do not want the name to be 'mangled' (your C functions) use 'extern C { ... }' in the C header files.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can't invoke the constructor, directly, but you can create factory functions that allocate and return instances of your object, and you can write these functions such that the definition is provided in C++ (where it is possible to use "new" to allocate the object and use the C++ constructors) but callable from C.

In the header, you should write:

```
 #ifdef __cplusplus
 #  define EXTERNC extern "C"
 #  define NOTHROW noexcept
 #else
 #  define EXTERNC
 #  define NOTHROW
 #endif

 /* Alias for your object in C that hides the implementation */
 typedef void* mylibraryname_mytype_t;

 /* Creates the object using the first constructor */
 EXTERNC mylibraryname_mytype_t mylibraryname_create_mytype() NOTHROW;

 /* Creates the object using the second constructor */
 EXTERNC mylibraryname_mytype_t mylibraryname_create_mytype_with_int(int val) NOTHROW;

 /* Frees the object, using delete */
 EXTERNC void mylibraryname_free_mytype(mylibraryname_mytype_t obj) NOTHROW;
```

Then in your C++ source file, you can do:

```
 EXTERNC mylibraryname_mytype_t mylibraryname_create_mytype() NOTHROW {
   try {
     return static_cast<mylibraryname_mtype_t>(new MyType);
   }
   catch (...) {
     return nullptr;
   }
 }

 EXTERNC mylibraryname_mytype_t create_mytype_with_int(int val) NOTHROW {
   try {
     return static_cast<mylibraryname_mytype_t>(new MyType(val));
   }
   catch (...) {
       return nullptr;
   }
 }

 EXTERNC void mylibraryname_free_mytype(mylibraryname_mytype_t obj) NOTHROW {
   try {
     MyType* typed_obj = static_cast<MyType*>(obj);
     delete typed_obj;
   }
   catch (...) {
       // Ignore
   }
 }
```

Your C code should then be able to include the same header and use the definition from the C++ source file when linked against the generated library.

Note that the code above is swallowing exceptions wholesale. For a real API, you should provide a way of indicating errors to the caller (e.g. by returning the allocated object via an output parameter and returning a status code) rather than merely suppressing them.

**Edit**
As noted in the comments, "_t" is technically a reserved suffix (though you should be fine if your symbols have a prefix that is unlikely to be used by standard libraries in the future), so just make sure that your symbols include the library name as a prefix. It should also be noted that the typedef, though not required, is intended to make uses of the object more self-documenting than a raw "void*" all over the place.

Comment: Thanks for that soultion @Michael Aaron Safyan. I have some questions about that snippet: that code you wrote, should I add this to the parser-.c file or to my project-.cpp file ? And are "mytype_t" and "MyType" just random variable names or do I have to change their name to my class/constructors name ?

Comment: I just used "mytype" for the sake of illustration. You would probably change it to match the type of your actual object. The header would be a *.h file corresponding to your type, and the source would be a *.cpp file. You'd include the *.h file in the *.c file and invoke these functions from there.

Comment: Alright i check this solution and accept this answer if everything worked out.

Comment: `mytype_t` is a terrible idea for a `typedef`. Suffix `_t` is reserved in many contexts, and the name should definitively reflect the fact that this is a pointer type. Even better would be to avoid it all along and have an explicit pointer in the signatures of the functions.

Comment: @JensGustedt, even though "_t" is reserved, if the name of the function has the library name and the type in the prefix, it's unlikely to be an issue, and it is more consistent with existing C code. The typedef is more for the calling code than for the implementation. The code that uses this API will be a lot more clear if it uses "mytype_t" rather than "void*" (if you have void* all over the place, possibly corresponding to different types, it is a lot less self-documenting than typedefs for specific uses of "void*").

Comment: Just make sure you also do `try ... catch ...` around the `new` call [and any other that may in any way may "throw"].

Comment: Good call, @MatsPetersson. I'll update to include "noexcept".

Comment: The `noexcept` solution may be good enough, but it's very important to understand that "letting C++ exceptions escape into C" is definitely a bad thing.

Comment: Yep. It is undefined behavior. My understanding is that "noexcept" will cause the C++ compiler to insert a call to terminate() rather than propagating the exception out of the function.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan, "_t" really shouldn't be used by user code. And for the interface I didn't say that this shouldn't use a `typedef` nor that it shouldn't use a pointer. But the `typedef` should be to the `struct` (as an opaque type) and the `*` should be explicit in all interfaces.

Comment: The type is a C++ class, so it isn't reasonable to typedef the actual structure (and even if it were, it is useful to hide for the sake of encapsulation).

Comment: Could you provide a citation for avoiding `_t`? I've seen quite a lot of C code use `thing_t` for things that have been typedef'd.

Comment: It's reserved by the ISO C standard. This is documented in the glibc documentation: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html