# How to force Eclipse to use g++ instead of gcc?

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, compiler-construction, g++

I already asked how to call a C++ constructor from a C file in [How to call a C++ constructor from a C-File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237756/is-calling-a-c-constructor-from-a-c-file-possible?noredirect=1#comment37464698_24237756). Now when I successfully apply these methods suggested there, I receive an error

> fatal error: string: No such file or directory compilation terminated

this error message points to the line: `#include <string>` in a header of a .cpp file.

I already found out that `<string>` is used by c++/g++ and `<string.h>` by c/gcc. Well the problem got clearer, when I checked the console output and there I can see, the (.cpp) file with the error was *called* by the gcc, which actually expects the `<string.h>` but that's not my intention - I need to compile it with the g++.

**Now my question is**: Can I force Eclipse to use a specific compiler? Here, for example just g++ (I heared it is capable of C-code too.) - Or even better, is there a way to chose the compiler for each directory in the workspace ?

Thanks for your advises

Comment: How do you compile from eclipse? By pressing run?

Comment: In order to compile c++ you need to first select a c++ project in eclipse, then you can include c header and source files as usual.

Comment: @pipja thanks this is right. My project is mixed with C and C++ Files and for some reason, Eclipse starts compiling with the C files (gcc) and gets then confused when it comes to touch the .cpp s

Comment: if you add `-x c++` to the command line arguments, compilation should work with `gcc` just fine. There probably is a setting for manually set parameters somewhere.

Comment: okay got it now, I set it under `GCC C Compiler/Dialect/Other dialect flags` but now even more errors are generated, I have to check this first.

Comment: You can specify it somewhere in your project compiler settings, I'm mobile now so can't check the exact location. I used it before to force other versions (e.g. 4.7 or 4.8).

Comment: @user3085931 That'll be C++ then!

Answer (score 1):

Answer respecting the wish of being **able to specify the compiler for every subfolder**:

What you are searching is probably a **[makefile](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Fgetting_started%2Fcdt_w_newproj.htm)** project. That allows you to specify the toolchain, being for example the preprocessor, compiler and linker. g++ is an example for such a toolchain, as much as clang++ would be.

You can generate such a project in eclipse, writing the makefiles by hand, or use some build environment, such as [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/), which I would recommend for better portable code.

Both solutions would allow you to specify the compiler, as well as the compile flags, for every single directory of your project, if you wished so.

[Writing a makefile for your existing C/C++ project](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_new_make.htm) can be achieved by completing the following steps:

1. in the folder where your source file is, right click and create a new file. `New > File`
2. name it `makefile` and click `Finish`
3. The new makefile should pop up in the editor and can be filled like follows:

   ```
   makefile:
   all: executable_name

   clean:
       -rm main.o executable_name[.exe on windows] executable_name

   executable_name: main.o
       g++ -g -o executable_name main.o

   main.o: main.cpp
       g++ -c -g main.cpp
   ```

Comment: If everything else fails, I know I have to write my own makefile. But I hoped it would be possible, for this purpose, to use the Eclipse Makefile-"Wizzard" too. I'm looking for the easiest solution, that I don't have to care about, whenever something changes.

Comment: thank you for your help. Writing a makefile is connected with time for maintanance, where I expect that Eclipse could do this job for me.

Comment: @user3085931 That's why I would recommend CMake, it might be more time consuming to start with, but it is by far easier to maintain I'd say.

Comment: Right now I have about 20(+20 header)-files and around 10 c files, but files come and go, especially when I try to integrate another program - So I think the expenditure is pretty big. I'm looking for generic solution, do you think cmake will keep me away from days about configuring a "random" makefile? I've never tried cmake so I can't assess if this will become a time eating option, but I believe it is, since it's about writing on my own

Comment: @user3085931 in cmake as well as in makefiles you have the possibility to make use of all (many) kind of native tools to automatically compile all c/c++ files.

Answer (score 0):

Change Project's Setting can force eclipse to compile using g++:
[image: Project Settings]

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, years ago I moved on from this. However if i remember correctly plausible approaches like yours didn't work that's why I was asking of how to *force* to use the g++. I believe this was some kind of automatism, where Eclipse changed the compiler when he reads c-libraries, or just a bug.

Comment: ha.i found the correct way was to change eclipse project type from c project to c++ project.

Comment: Thanks for the hint but pardon me for I can't double check it anymore. I think it's a strange kind of behavior anyway, since I always believed Eclipse is using a makefile for compiling/linking in the end, filled with the parameters in the menu you have shown above.